# How do i prioritize the switch() case rather than other function

Tags: c++

So i make a turn based dos game, And i have a switch() function which gives me a bug.. :

```
int hp;
int mana;
do
{
    cout<<"Enter your arg here";
    cin>>choice;
    cout<<"Hahaha that won't stop me";
    switch(choice)
    {
      case 1:
        mana--;
        mana--;
        hp--;
        hp--;
        cout<<"Woosh";
    }
}
while(1)
{
  cout<<endl;
}
```

Ok so let me explain the bug :

1. When the player inputs choice variable it will just skip the switch() function an just go continue with cout<<"Hahaha that won't stop me";. How do i fix that?
   PS : Sorry for my bad english, and if there is a misswriting on this post. I'm so sorry about that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre], and [edit] your question to show it.

Comment: thx bro for helping me formatting the code!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, switch is not a function, it's a statement. That means, it doesn't behave like functions. What you've written here doesn't match with what you want.
What the program does is:

1. printing the first line
2. reading the input
3. printing the second line
4. switching on the input

What you want is:

1. printing the first line
2. reading the input
3. switching on the input
4. printing the second line on default case

So let's reorder your code.

```
cout << "Enter your arg here";
cin >> choice;
switch (choice)
{
  case 1:
    mana -= 2;
    hp -= 2;
    cout << "Woosh";
    break;
  default:
    cout << "Hahaha that won't stop me";
    break;
}
```

And don't forget to write `break;` on every case, including default one.

Comment: ahhh i see it now, thanks! will give you a rep if i get 15 rep alr

Comment: ehh wtf it got a new bug KhoDis...

Comment: may i give you all of my code?